# Access Caching ODBC connection settings

Tags: ms-access, odbc

My company uses SAI heavily and in order to create reports from this system we use ODBC to connect to the DB. Our setup at the moment is regional and thus we have separate environments for each region. When trying to access these environments using MS ACCESS I am finding that I cannot link to tables in different environments and retrieve accurate data.

I can create the links to various environments using the specific DSN's. I then can access the data, however the first table that I open, no matter the region it belongs to, works fine.  After that, however, all of the tables, regardless to the region they belong to, all use the DSN settings from the first table that was opened.  If I shut Access down and restart I can then start with data from another environment which will then work, however the rest of the data will then reflect those DSN settings. Additionally, when I look at the property sheet the DSN settings are as they should be.

Let me also add that the tables for each region all have the same name. IE the sales table is sales in all environments, the production table is the production table in all regions. As a result as I link to the sales table from multiple environments the need to be renamed in MS ACCESS.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564265/how-to-refresh-linked-tables-in-an-access-mdb-when-odbc-changes/564454#564454) answered a last month.

It describes a couple of methods for forcing Access to re-link ODBC tables and, if all fails, provides you with a way to restart the database programmatically using a small [function that you'll find on my blog](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2008/ms-access-restarting-the-database-programmatically/).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you leaving out a few details that we need.

When you open that first table, are you prompted for a logon? (this is critical info). If you using “different” links and saving the userid/password in those links, then you should not get any ODBC prompts and you can thus easily work with more than one region.

However, it sounds like you have one set of links, and want to re-point/re-link to a different server. This can work - but NOT if you seeing/allowing ODBC prompts.

If you ARE including the userid/password in the links then you should be able to re-link (switch) to either system. However when you do this, then BOTH uid/password combos ARE and WILL be active at that same given time.

Where things go VERY wrong is that if you re-link with an incorrect logon then the previous uid/password WILL be used! And in fact if you TEST for a logon (even a bad one!), then the first legal logon will be used! At the end of the day, this means the weak point here is WHEN/if you ask for a logon, it WILL return “yes” for a legal logon EVEN if the logon is bad! (because Access will revent to the previous legal logon used) You MUST deal with this issue.

So likely things point to your code that does a logon “test” before re-link. What I would suggest is that your “test” logon code returns OK, you THEN execute a pass-through query to return the database name – if that database name/server is wrong, then you reject that logon and do NOT re-link.

So critical here is how you are testing for the new logon/server? And you most certainly NEVER want the ODBC logon prompt to appear – since if a user cancel, or enters the wrong logon, then your re-link code will use the previous cached logon.

You should be able to re-link the same given set of tables and point them to another server – but you need to ensure that the logon you used did in fact work.

Last but not least:
Access ALWAYS uses a DSN less connection. The ONLY exception is if you are using a system DSN. So when you create a file DSN, and re-link then the DSN FROM THAT point on is ignored, and not used. (this allows you to say distribute the application to other desktops without having to copy/include a DSN). So in effect you near always using a DSN-less connection and if you are not, then I suggest you dump the SYSTEM DSN’s, since Access cannot use the USER/password from such system DSN’s – even if you include the USER/password in that DSN it is STILL ignored.

Also when you re-link, are you using the dbAttachSavePWD – you should not have to, but I would for testing include it.

If you are using/allowing the ODBC driver to prompt the user for a logon – then you have to eliminate this and ensure your code does the logon.

Answer (score 0):

One option you may have (though a bit long winded) would be to create an access database for each region which links to one regions tables. eg have the sales table and production table for region Europe in one access database, and put those from ASIA into another database.

Once you have this set up, you might find it much easier to then use a third access database to link to the two other access databases.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Yes very long winded, and Access didnt like that solution either.

Comment: ohh well it was worth a try.  Might have to resort to static tables then.

Comment: I am trying  Sql Server first.  It looks promising.  I just have very little experience with sql server!